# Spring Boot Application:- The import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication cannot be resolved

Tags: maven, spring-boot

I'm beginner for Spring-boot;refering some tutorials I have set up a spring boot project using the Spring Initializer. I have tried to get rid of this issue by downloading dependencies again and even created new projects several times.

I'm using Eclipse neon IDE and I find error on imports import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.

I have removed repositories too many times so that jars will auto downloaded by itself when I refresh\clean the project but problem still persists.

DemoApplication.java

```
package com.example.demo;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
  }
}
```

below is my pom.xml

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>demo</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>demo</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <start-class>com.example.demo.DemoApplication</start-class>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Does the problem only occur in Eclipse, or does building on the command line with Maven also fail? Have you checked that `spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar` has been added to your Eclipse project's classpath and that the jar file in Maven's local repository hasn't been corrupted. You could check the latter with `jar -tf`.

Comment: Yes, It was eclipse issue I found corrupted jars in repository and upgraded m2e to 1.8(solution found in Eclipse forum). After upgrading m2e I had removed my repository and restarted eclipse. Everything worked smooth 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was eclipse issue I found corrupted jars in repository and upgraded m2e to 1.8(solution found in Eclipse forum). After upgrading m2e I had removed my repository and restarted eclipse. Everything worked smooth

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this, I think this would solve

```
public static void main(final String[] aArgs)
  {
    new SpringApplicationBuilder(DemoApplication.class).run(aArgs);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

within Eclipse: Right click *Project -> Maven -> Update project* should work

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue while converting the existing project to Springboot application

> click on project -> Add Framework Support -> select maven

This worked.